# Can google analytics gave me stats for different url's on same domain

Tags: api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

### Scenario

I am working on a web application assume it **www.abc.com** which having a profile for all users

```
www.abc.com/username
```

and all users have a dashboard for controlling their profiles

### Requirement

i have one analytics profile for **www.abc.com** but my requirement is 
a to show stats to all users on their dashboard

can i get this by google analytics API

1. Visits
2. demographics
3. all traffic source
4. and keywords

i have integrated reporting by API on one of my project but that is for the domain . i am not sure for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

**Resource-guru.com**, what you can do is to pull all the data with *page path* dimension included, and then simply filter the results if the username string is found in the page path.

As for the second part of your question - **you can get**:

- visits (metric)
- traffic sources as well as keywords (dimensions, but remember [(not provided)](http://www.notprovidedcount.com/) might make this useless report)

you **can NOT get** demographics data via API.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the API to do this but remember your going to have an issue with the fact that you can only make 10k requests per day per view (profile).

The Demographics report displays age and gender.  Those dimensions can be found under the [Audience - Dimensions & Metrics Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=audience)

```
ga:visitorAgeBracket
ga:visitorGender
ga:interestOtherCategory
ga:interestAffinityCategory
```

[Traffic Source](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033173?hl=en) is just really just a mix up of [ga:sourceMedium](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=traffic_sources&jump=ga_sourcemedium) , [ga:campaign](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=traffic_sources&jump=ga_campaign) maybe a few others depending on what information you want to display.

You may have issues with Keywords because due to ssl and trying to keep user info private Google has stopped recording this sometimes you get (not provided).  But you can get that information from webmaster tools.  Its just hard to merge it with your GA data then.

> Keyword: The keywords that visitors searched are usually captured in
>   the case of search engine referrals. This is true for both organic and
>   paid search. Note, however, that when SSL search is employed, Keyword
>   will have the value (not provided).